# With limited training time - should I shrink the training set and run more epochs?

Tags: deep-learning, train

I wonder what is considered a better practice in deep learning. I have a dataset of 100K images that I want to use for training a regional-CNN for a whole week.

Is it possible that my network will be better trained if I shrink the dataset, throwing away 75% of the samples (suppose that the data is shuffled and that every class has equal number of samples), just because it will run 4 times more epochs on it?

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely (over-)fit your training data "better" and generalize worse. You may want to look into better algorithms, parallelization and renting compute on the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my settings, would you prefer 20 epochs on 100k images rather than 80 epochs on 25k images? Will the "generalization" with 20 epochs be worthy?

Comment: Fewer epochs with more images should do better in generalization, because each batch contains more information. We normally spend a lot of effort to augment data (rotation, cropping etc.) to get more "data" to reduce overfitting, which is normally not as good as completely new photos, so I very much expect that. Perhaps look into more efficient implementations (e.g. have you had a look at what e.g. the fast.ai library has to offer)? Think about starting with down-scaled photos then upscale (fast.ai did that for training imagenet super-fast - you might want to read their blog-post on that)?